# Creating object from JSON and parsing JSON - different results

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to use JQuery to parse some JSON being sent back from an AJAX call. It appears to be failing to parse, and JSLint also says it's invalid JSON.

However, if I create the object directly, it works and I am able to loop through it  - please see below:

```
var json = {layers:[{layer1:[17,16,15,14,12]}]}
alert(json)// <- This works and output object Object

var somestring = "{layers:[{layer1:[17,16,15,14,12]}]}"
var parsing = JSON.parse(somestring)
alert(parsing) // <- this doesn't and breaks on parse

// The below code will work provided the parsing is commented out

json.layers.forEach(function (outerObj)
{
    Object.keys(outerObj).forEach(function (key)
    {
        outerObj[key].forEach(function (item)
        {
            alert(item)
        });
    });
});
```

I'm struggling to wrap my head around why it won't parse, but appears to work.

**Edit**

I realise by wrapping quotes around `layers` and `layer1` fixes it, just not sure why it works one way - but not the other.

Comment: If you're using the AJAX functions in jQuery (with data type set to JSON) you won't have to parse it - jQuery does that for you. Trying to parse an already-parsed JSON string will give you an error iirc.

Comment: Great tip, thanks very much. Totally forgot about dataType am using this now.

Comment: JSON keys officially should be with surrounded with apices. When you have a JSON object string, it expects you use JSON syntax correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a difference between javascript object and JSON object, all keys of JSON object must be quoted.

```
var somestring = "{layers:[{layer1:[17,16,15,14,12]}]}"// not a valid json to parse, it is a normal string, you can use JSON.stringify() to make it a valid json identifiable string.
```

so the correct JSON string will look like

```
var somestring = '{"layers":[{"layer1":[17,16,15,14,12]}]}';
var parsedJson = JSON.parse(somestring)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've accepted this as it addresses the question showing the difference between the two methods - one being JS and one bring JQuery

Answer (score 0):

If you change `sometring` to some of the following examples, it will works.

```
var somestring = '{"layers":[{"layer1":[17,16,15,14,12]}]}'

var somestring = "{\"layers\":[{\"layer1\":[17,16,15,14,12]}]}"
```

The reason for this is, basically, that's how JSON was specified.

For further examples, take a look at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Best practice is to use `JSON.stringify(Object)` on one side, and `JSON.parse(String)` on the other. This will save you many hours of scratching your head over some niggling detail.

In your example, you could resolve the problem by

```
var somestring = JSON.stringify(json)
```

For future reference, however, JSON keys must be quoted, so your `somestring` should be written as:

```
var somestring = '{"layers":[{"layer1":[17,16,15,14,12]}]}'
```

Good luck!

Comment: JSON strings must be quoted with `"` not `'`.

Comment: Haha! See what I mean about niggling details! Fixed.